# String is converted to DateTime when putting it to a System.Data.DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm populating a datatable with values, and one of them is the following string: "1/1/1801".
In my array "values", that item is of String type.
But when I assign the array to a System.Data.DataTable row, it magically turns into a datetime type:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow().ItemArray = values);
```

Waht's going on here and is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can easily help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the type of the `DataColumn` so the table knows it is a `string`.

```
DataRow row; 

// Create new DataColumn, set DataType, ColumnName and add to DataTable.    
column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "Whatever";
table.Columns.Add(column);
```

Then when you ask for `NewRow` it will know what each column's data type is.

Comment: Right, I was determining the column type by the value in the first row, and the invalid date came in the second row so it got casted to DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the columns to the data table.Directly adding a row will throw run time error "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

You must have to declare and add column with its type as string.

```
            string[] values = new string[] { "1/1/1801" };
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));          
            dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow().ItemArray = values);
```